# insert python list in all rows new pd.Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have python list:

```
my_list = [1, 'V']
```

I have pd.Dataframe:

```
   A  B  C
0  f  v  b
1  f  i  n
2  f  i  m
```

I need to create new column in my dataframe with value = `my_list`:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  f  v  b  [1, 'V']
1  f  i  n  [1, 'V']
2  f  i  m  [1, 'V']
```

As far as I understand python lists can be values, bc `df.groupby` with apply "list":

```
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], group_keys=True)['C'].apply(list).reset_index(name='H')
```

```
   A  B       H
0  f  i  [n, m]
1  f  v     [b]
```

Its posible without convert `my_list` type? What the the easiest way to do that?

I tried:

```
df['D'] = my_list
```

```
df['D'] = pd.Series(my_list)
```

but they did not meet my expectations

Comment: what u want exactly? just adding a constant list as a new column to every row? or something else

Comment: @AminS yes. Just add existing list in all rows of new column

Comment: `df['D'] = [my_list] * len(df)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using: np.repeat and set its repeat parameter to number of rows which can be found out from the shape of the dataframe.

```
my_list = [1, 'V']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['f', 'f', 'f'], 'col2': ['v', 'i', 'i'], 'col3': ['b', 'n', 'm']})
df['new_col'] = np.repeat(my_list, df.shape[0])
```

This will repeat the values of my_list as many times as there are rows in the DataFrame.

Comment: Its raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (3)